# Resolved git merge conflict in VS Code, but still says unresolved

Tags: git, merge, visual-studio-code, merge-conflict-resolution

So I have a develop branch and topic branch. I'm using the default Terminal in Window's VS Code. While in the topic branch, I did `git merge develop` since I just got latest on develop branch. Now there's a simple merge conflict in one file. In VS Code, I resolved the conflict. On the code page, there's no more conflicts that you can `Accept Incoming` or `Accept Current`, but when I try to stage the file on the Source Control panel on the left, it shows a warning popup saying `Are you sure you want to stage with merge conflicts?`

Is this normal? it seems like VS Code doesn't think I resolved the conflict even tho I just did, and there's no more conflict in the file. Or is there something I'm missing Git/VS Code-wise?

Comment: Did you do a `git add <file>` after resolving the conflict?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, isn't `git add <file>` the same as staging a file?

Comment: Make sure that conflict markers are not in the file. <<<<<<< HEAD

Comment: @ShashwatKumar could you elaborate on how to check that or how to remove it?

Comment: open the file and search for this string.

Comment: This is an open issue in VSCode from version 1.16.0 https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33983

Comment: @IslamEl-Khayat this is the exact issue, thanks for the link, didn't know it was a bug!

Answer (score 18):

It is an normal behavior. Usually we will get the merge conflicts when we have changes changes in same line of source and destination files of merging.

In your case, you have resolved your conflicts in your file(i mean vs code) but it is not updated to git. So after adding *`Accept Incoming`* or *`Accept Current`* you have to do below steps,

1. git add `<conflicts resolved files>`
2. git commit -m "`merge conflict resolved message`"
3. git push

Answer (score 11):

In VSCode when you have conflicts in multiple files, they're shown in the git panel and you can open files one by one and resolve them.

When you resolve the conflicts in a file, you should save the file then click the `+` button of that file (shown in the image bellow).

[image: Stage resolved file]

This will result in staging the file. If you click this button and there's unresolved conflicts in that file, you'll get this message:

> Are you sure you want to stage with merge conflicts?

Now if you resolve conflicts of all files and click on the `+` button that is above all files (to stage all files with conflict) (Shown in the image bellow), it'll still give you the same message (Although you've already resolved all conflicts).

[image: stage all files]

So I recommend that you click the `+` of each file individually so that you'll be sure that you resolved all conflicts before staging the file.

#### Note

I believe this bug is fixed in recent versions of VSCode.

Comment: I can't find the MERGE CHANGES section in my source control panel ! Am I missing something ?

Comment: @ngCoder No that section is displayed only when you have conflicts.

Comment: Yes I got that but I do have conflicts as my pull failed,still no sign of this section.Some config is missing ?

Comment: This can be done using below command using cmd

````git remote update````
````git merge origin/Vishal-Develop -X theirs````
````git commit -m commit -m "New release"````
````git push --recurse-submodules=check --progress "origin" refs/heads/Vishal-Master````
Please use branch names accordingly

Comment: My VSCode wouldn't let me click the + button with "conflicts" but `git add <file>` worked just fine.

Comment: @ngCoder make sure that you installed the git extension

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I realized I had ***Auto Save*** turned off. I know, it's too silly. But worth checking.

Comment: This is exactly my case. Thank you!

Comment: THe same case here :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

[image: Confilig Image]

You can see the Confilig classes here in Android Studio. It does not appear on Github desktop, but it appears here. You can merge it after solving it from here. The same is true for other ideas.